# shapekey driver expression update

Tags: python, drivers

I have a script that updates shapekeys, and as such has an impact on the driver expressions.
I'm trying to find and automated way to update dependencies on the shapekey drivers every time I update a shapekey (ideally on the active object).

I did find this script but it doesn't work on shapekeys as per the comment -

```
import bpy

# not include shape-key driver because they are not in animation_data.drivers
def update_driver(obj):
    try:
        for fc in obj.animation_data.drivers:
            fc.driver.expression = fc.driver.expression
    except:
        pass

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    update_driver(obj)
```

I also found a bunch of topics modifying those expressions, like adding "_" and removing [:-1] to force an update, but I'd very much like to avoid that.

Is it possible to just update the dependencies/expression evaluation in a loop for the active objects shapekeys?

Comment: shape keys have their own animation data. Have a look at 'obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.drivers'.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. I really appreciate it.